# How to generate a realistic fluid sim splash?

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm trying to have an object splash into a fluid, but I've been getting pretty strange results out of my fluid sim. The most frustrating is the effect in the gif below, where the "splash" awkwardly clings to the object before "evaporating:"

[image]

This is with a final rendering resolution of 250 and the domain settings below:

[image]

Is there any way to get a bigger and more realistic splash out of this scene? The impact factor of the obstacle is currently at 1.5.

Comment: There is a relatively high quality open source fluid simulator, called mantaflow. Site: http://mantaflow.com/  You can download it built in Blender here:http://graphicall.org/

Comment: Alternatively you can either built or buy a version of the Flip-Fluids Addon

Comment: Thank you! I've been struggling with splashes in mantaflow as well. Is it true, then, that the built-in fluid sim will not be able to generate this effect without the strange artifacts demonstrated above?